# Unusual Shapes on Baked Normal Map

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map, error

So, I am basically trying to bake a normal map from my high poly mesh to low poly retopologized mesh. But I got some unusual shapes on my normal map. Some areas just work fine.

High Poly render sample here: [image]. Low Poly render sample here: [image]. Sample from normal map here: [image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, it was actually about the displace modifier that I used for retopology process. When I just removed the modifier, the unusual shapes on the normal map are disapeared and I finally got a clear normal map.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ray distance in the Selective to Active window of Cycles Bake. When in doubt, set it to 1 meter and it will capture all the data it needs. Good luck by the way!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I've already tried to set its value between 0 and 1, and beyond but I got more awkward results. I am now also sending the image of colliding meshes in this link: https://imgur.com/6GhhUYD (Green one is low poly mesh and white one is the high poly mesh. Maybe my mistake is about the collision of these two meshes.)

Comment: There is actually a fairly large difference between the original high poly model and retopologized model. That would explain why you are seeing green on your normal maps, however the unusual shapes in the normal map are still strange.